The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (serverless and s3)
I am very new to serverless and lambda functions. I have an application where I need to use the S3 service. When I test credentials created manually in my AWS account, I can access these services. However, when I try to use it from serverless, I am encountering this issue: InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
**serverless.yaml **
org: juan
app: knot
service: knot-be
provider:
  environment:
    APP_ENV: staging
    ...... env variables.....
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: us-east-1
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - "*/*"
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::knot-be/*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "ses:SendEmail"
        - "ses:SendRawEmail"
      Resource: "*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "rds:*"
      Resource: "*"
  ecr:
    images:
      appimage:
        path: ./
functions:
  api:
    image:
      name: appimage
      command: 
        - dist/lambda.handler
      entryPoint:
        - '/lambda-entrypoint.sh'
    timeout: 30    
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: any
      - http:
          path: /
          method: any
resources:
  Resources:
    Bloodknot3Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: knot-be

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

**this is my s3.config.ts **
const s3Config = {
  bucketName: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME || 'bloodknot-storage-dev',
  region: (process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-east-2') as BucketLocationConstraint,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || '',
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || '',
  },
}

const s3Client = new S3Client(s3Config)


export {
  s3Config,
  GetObjectCommand,
  PutObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectCommand,
  ListObjectsV2Command,
  S3Client,
  getSignedUrl,
}

export default s3Client

And I created an endpoint to check if I have available AWS variables and ofcourse I have them in a response from the deploy server:
{ "bucketName": "knot-be", "region": "us-east-1", "credentials": { "accessKeyId": "ASIA.....", "secretAccessKey": "qG....." } }
But i'm still having the same issue, even if I try this in the server or with local variables:
[Nest] 5538  - 05/07/2024, 1:00:21 AM   ERROR [S3StorageProvider] InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
[Nest] 5538  - 05/07/2024, 1:00:21 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Error uploading file at 6b613615-af7b-4408-8566-89e9a5f08872
Error: Error uploading file at 6b613615-af7b-4408-8566-89e9a5f08872
    at S3StorageProvider.uploadFile (/home/seb/Desktop/knotblood/bloodknot-backend/src/commons/providers/file-storage/s3/s3-storage.provider.ts:125:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

Why does it work on my local machine when I use my own AWS variables, but I still get this error when I use serverless variables, even if I use them locally too? Is there something I'm doing wrong with my serverless file, or is there some additional configuration I need to do in AWS to use this with serverless?
I hope the application works because when I use variables that I create manually, the whole system works. However, when it's from serverless, nothing works and it just generates this error.

An access key that starts with ASIA is a temporary access key generated by the AWS Security Token Service. For example, they are generated when an IAM Role is assigned to an EC2 instance. Is your app running on an EC2 instance? Where did the Access Key & Secret Key come from? How were they assigned to Environment Variables?

What happens if you remove the entire credentials: { ... }, block from s3Config? It seems incomplete but also unnecessary since the correct environment variables should be used automatically.
